# Fast computation of warp matrices

Tags: image, performance, matlab

For a fixed and given tform, the imwarp command in the Image Processing Toolbox

```
  B = imwarp(A,tform)
```

is linear with respect to A, meaning there exists some sparse matrix W, **depending on tform but independent of A**, such that the above can be equivalently implemented

```
  B(:)=W*A(:)
```

for all A of fixed known dimensions [n,n]. My question is whether there are fast/efficient options for computing W. The matrix form is necessary when I need the transpose operation W.'*B(:), or if I need to do W\B(:) or similar linear algebraic things which I can't do directly through imwarp alone.

I know that it is possible to compute W column-by-column by doing

```
   E=zeros(n);
   W=spalloc(n^2,n^2,4*n^2);

   for i=1:n^2

    E(i)=1;
     tmp=imwarp(E,tform);
    E(i)=0;

    W(:,i)=tmp(:);

   end
```

but this is brute force and slow.

The routine [FUNC2MAT](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44669-func2mat-convert-linear-function-to-matrix) is somewhat more optimal in that it uses the loop to compute/gather the sparse entry data I,J,S of each column W(:,i). Then, after the loop, it uses this to construct the overall sparse matrix. It also offers the option of using a PARFOR loop. However, this is still slower than I would like.

Can anyone suggest more speed-optimal alternatives?

**EDIT:**

For those uncomfortable with my claim that imwarp(A,tform) is linear w.r.t. A, I include the demo script below, which tests that the superposition property is satisfied for random input images and tform data. It can be run repeatedly to see that the `nonlinearityError` is always small, and easily attributable to floating point noise.

```
tform=affine2d(rand(3,2));
 %tform=projective2d(rand(3));

fun=@(A) imwarp(A,tform,'cubic');

I1=rand(100); I2=rand(100);
c1=rand; c2=rand;


LHS=fun(c1*I1+c2*I2);  %left hand side
RHS=c1*fun(I1)+c2*fun(I2); %right hand side

linearityError = norm(LHS(:)-RHS(:),'inf')
```

Comment: I'm not sure you example code where you say that you can compute `W` makes sense. Are you omitting steps? Shouldn't `imwarp` return a matrix? Yet you're setting it equal to a column of `W`. And have you pre-allocated `W`? Also, there seem to be no need for reshaping and using sparse if you're just going to create a full matrix for the "`A`" that you're passing into `imwarp`. Let `E = zeros(n);`. Then on each iteration, `E(i) = 1;` before passing into `imwarp` and `E(i) = 0;` afterwards to undo.

Comment: @horchler I've fixed the presentation of the for-loop so that W(:,i) is assigned a properly shaped and sparse column vector. Yes, I  initially skipped showing the pre-allocation of W to improve readability, but it is pre-allocated and I've included that now. FUNC2MAT actually does something smarter than this, using the loop to pre-compute the sparse table data I,J,S before constructing W.

Comment: @Jigg The entries of W will depend on the tform, but imwarp is a linear function of A and therefore it must have a Jacobian independent of A. The Jacobian is W. To put it in 1D terms, The slope m of a line y=m*x never depends on x. Not sure why you propose imwarp(ones(size(A)), tform). The warping of a uniform image is another uniform image, for any reasonable interpolator.

Comment: @Jigg interpolation/resampling is very much a linear operation w.r.t the pixel values, for any conventional interpolator. I have edited my question to include a demo script showing the linear properties. You can try different tform and interpolators if you wish, but I am confident that you will always see the superposition property satisfied to within floating point precision.

Comment: Here, m is what I've been calling W? You can compute it by downloading func2mat from the link I gave and running    `m=func2mat(@(A) imwarp(A,tform,'cubic'), zeros(N))`. You can use any tform for this, be it a translation or otherwise.

Comment: I wonder if this thread is of interest to you. I think it gives the general method for what you are after, but not the details of implementation: http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/05/05/spatial-transformations-inverse-mapping/

Comment: This might give you T-1, haven't tried anything though. http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/tforminv.html

Answer (score 0):

That's actually pretty simple:

```
W = sparse(B(:)/A(:));
```

Note that W is not unique, but this operation probably produces the most sparse result. Another way to calculate it would be

```
W = sparse( B(:) * pinv(A(:)) );
```

but that results in a much less sparse (yet still valid) result.

Comment: Thanks, but no, as I mention in my post, I am looking for the matrix such that B(:)=W*A(:) is equivalent to the operation B=imwarp(A,tform) for _all_ nxn input images A, not just one particular given A. The matrix W that does this is unique and cannot be obtained just from a single input/output pair A,B.

Comment: Oh, now I see what you're trying to do. This pretty much comes down to implementing your own version of imwarp. If you have only a few tforms, you could write one transform function/matrix for each of them, but if you need the versatility of an arbitrary tform, there's no way around writing your own matrix version of imwrap or using the approach you mention in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I constructed the warping matrix using the optical flow fields [u,v] and it is working well for my application

```
% this function computes the warping matrix

% M x N is the size of the image

function [ Fw ] = generateFwi( u,v,M,N )

  Fw = zeros(M*N, M*N);

  k =1;

  for i=1:M

    for j= 1:N

      newcoord(1) = i+u(i,j);
      newcoord(2) = j+v(i,j);



      newi = newcoord(1);


      newj = newcoord(2);


      if newi >0 && newj >0

        newi1x = floor(newi);
        newi1y = floor(newj);
        newi2x = floor(newi);
        newi2y = ceil(newj);
        newi3x = ceil(newi);  % four nearest points to the given point
        newi3y = floor(newj);
        newi4x = ceil(newi);
        newi4y = ceil(newj);
        x1 = [newi,newj;newi1x,newi1y];
        x2 = [newi,newj;newi2x,newi2y];
        x3 = [newi,newj;newi3x,newi3y];
        x4 = [newi,newj;newi4x,newi4y];
        w1 = pdist(x1,'euclidean');
        w2 = pdist(x2,'euclidean');
        w3 = pdist(x3,'euclidean');
        w4 = pdist(x4,'euclidean');
        if ceil(newi) == floor(newi) && ceil(newj)==floor(newj)  % both the new coordinates are integers
          Fw(k,(newi1x-1)*N+newi1y) = 1;
        else if ceil(newi) == floor(newi)  % one of the new coordinates is an integer
          w = w1+w2;  
          w1new = w1/w;
          w2new = w2/w;
          W  = w1new*w2new;
          y1coord = (newi1x-1)*N+newi1y;
          y2coord = (newi2x-1)*N+newi2y;
          if y1coord <= M*N && y2coord <=M*N
            Fw(k,y1coord) = W/w2new;
            Fw(k,y2coord) = W/w1new;
          end
          else if ceil(newj) == floor(newj)  % one of the new coordinates is an integer
            w = w1+w3;
            w1 = w1/w;
            w3 = w3/w;
            W = w1*w3;
            y1coord = (newi1x-1)*N+newi1y;
            y2coord = (newi3x-1)*N+newi3y;
            if y1coord <= M*N && y2coord <=M*N
              Fw(k,y1coord) = W/w3;
              Fw(k,y2coord) = W/w1;
            end
            else        % both the new coordinates are not integers
              w  = w1+w2+w3+w4;
              w1 = w1/w;
              w2 = w2/w;
              w3 = w3/w;
              w4 = w4/w;
              W = w1*w2*w3 + w2*w3*w4 + w3*w4*w1 + w4*w1*w2;
              y1coord = (newi1x-1)*N+newi1y;
              y2coord = (newi2x-1)*N+newi2y;
              y3coord = (newi3x-1)*N+newi3y;
              y4coord = (newi4x-1)*N+newi4y;
              if y1coord <= M*N && y2coord <= M*N && y3coord <= M*N && y4coord <= M*N
                Fw(k,y1coord) = w2*w3*w4/W;
                Fw(k,y2coord) = w3*w4*w1/W;
                Fw(k,y3coord) = w4*w1*w2/W;  
                Fw(k,y4coord) = w1*w2*w3/W;
              end
            end
          end
        end
      else
        Fw(k,k) = 1;
      end
      k=k+1;
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: I fixed your indentation. It appears something's wrong. There are too many `end` and a misplaced `else`.

Comment: There are also `else if` expressions from C/C++ which don't exist in MATLAB. Possibly it was supposed to be `elseif`, but I can't tell for sure. I can run the code as is, but get a very incorrect result. It also looks like it's doomed to be terribly slow. Lots of for-loops with function calls nested inside them...

Comment: else if works well in matlab and there are only two for loops which traverses the image pixel by pixel to compute the new pixel coordinates. I think it is the only way to compute new coordinates at every pixel.

Comment: @gopi `else if` works but it has a different meaning than `elseif`.Together with the fact that I can't get the code to work it makes it unclear whether this was a bug. Further, you should know it is not the only way, because I've referred you to `FUNC2MAT` both in this thread and in others. FUNC2MAT only uses a single for-loop. When I do   `fun=@(X) interp2(X,x+u,y+v);
Fw=func2mat(fun,zeros(N));` I obtain Fw in 10 seconds for an NxN image with N=100 and 10000x1 deformation vectors u and v. The portion of the matrix that your code did compute took 25 times as long.

Comment: @gopi I recommend you repost your code with a data example for benchmarking. I also recommend that you supply an implementation which doesn't use pdist() since not everyone has the Stats Toolbox.